# Show that $F_1$ is a continuous linear functional in the normed space $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$?

Tags: analysis

$(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and $$F_1(f)=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{4}{3}} f(t) dt$$. Show that $F_1$ is a continuous linear functional.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (And btw, are the limits of integration correct, $4/3 > 1$?)

Comment: Yes they are correct. I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $F_1$ is a linear functional is due to the linearity of the integral. Moreover we have

$$\left|F_1(f)\right|\le\int_{\frac12}^{\frac43}|f(t)|dt\le \int_{\frac12}^{\frac43}||f||_\infty dt=\frac56||f||_\infty$$
and this inequality means that $F_1$ is continuous.